# BitmapImage filenotfound exception (PresentationCore.resources) on construction

Tags: c#, wpf, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem with a BitmapImage in wpf. When i create it it gives a filenotfound exception, which says it's missing the PresentationCore.resources assembly. But i've added it to my references list and it still throws the same exception

```
Uri filename = new Uri(@"D:\barcode_zwart_wit.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(filename); //<-- FileNotFound Exception
```

- The image uri is correct.
- The image isn't opened somewhere else
- I've checked the version of the PresentationCore.resources, no problem there.
- The lines are in the setter of a property, which is first launched in the constructor of a usercontrol.
- Visual Studio 2010, .net v4

Does anyone have any idea what's the problem? Does PresentationCore.resources have any dependencies i don't know about?

Comment: can you check what value "filename" is set to after initializing. I am suspecting something wrong with the file path.

Comment: already did, it gives a different exception when the filename is wrong.

Comment: I can think of following reasons why it would not function 1. no access to the location 2. file format is not supported 3. Image is being modified by some other application. You may need to post more details for someone to answer your query

Comment: allright, i've edited my question. Would there be any reason it doesn't have access or permission to my harddrive? its just a WPF Application.

Comment: I tried simulating the problem on my machine. But it is working just fine. I am using one of the default images in windows (desert.jpg)

Comment: thanks for trying, it's really strange. i just solved it by hacking something together, works but isn't pretty. Im adding an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve. it's an event which is called if a certain assembly can't be found.

in constructor:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve:

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string missingAssemblyName = args.Name.Remove(args.Name.IndexOf(',');
    if ( missingAssemblyName == "PresentationCore.resources" )
    {
         string s = "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationCore.resources.dll";
         return Assembly.LoadFile(s);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with the image's color profile being unavailable. Use BitmapImage.CreateOptions property to ignore color profile information as below:

```
var bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
bmp.UriSource = uri;
bmp.EndInit();
// Use the bmp variable for further processing and dispose it
```

I had the same issue with a few of `.jpg` images and this resolved it.